# Why do I only get the response header in Swift

Tags: swift, http-headers, nsurlsession

I'm trying to get the JSON from an web site and I'm using Swift.

Why do I get only the response header and not the body?

```
let headers = [
    "auth": key,
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
]

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: url)! as URL,
                                  cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                  timeoutInterval: 10.0)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

let session = URLSession.shared
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error!)
    } else {
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        print(httpResponse!)
        
    }
})

dataTask.resume()
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: What's in `data` in your callback ?

Comment: @Zyigh Optional(22169 bytes)

Comment: Sorry that was a rhetorical question. The body of the response you get is in data. If it is json data you might want to decode it, either with a [Decodable struct](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) or with [Swifty JSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) or whatever you want. Note that  it is optional so you can add a condition like `guard let data = data else { print("no data"); return }`

Comment: @Zyigh sorry I'm new in Swift 
So you're talking about the `data` in completionHandler, right?

Comment: Exactly! completionHandler is a callback (or closure...), this means it is a function that is called at some point during the execution of dataTask method. When dataTask get a response from the api call, it calls a function (completionHandler) with params that you can access with data, response and error. Error is pretty self explainatory, response is the response (headers mostly), and the data you get. As you may not have data, it is optional. Here's a swift 3 example that can be usefull to understand https://code.bradymower.com/swift-3-apis-network-requests-json-getting-the-data-4aaae8a5efc0